# TinyMCE not storing data in db properly

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

Im using `TinyMCE` but the problem is when im storing the `TinyMCE` data to db at my localhost it works properly but when im using same `TinyMCE` and storing into db on server it is not storing properly.I want to store data:-

```
The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
```

but in db it stores like(server) :-

```
The first line of Lorem Ipsum, \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..\", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
```

it appends "\" before ""(double codes) when im running my code on server(Linux)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Magic Quotes. `phpinfo()` on the page will tell you if they are active, and if they are, turn it off in your php.ini file.

Make sure these are all set to `Off`:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off 
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Comment: magic_quotes_runtime and magic_quotes_sybase are off but magic_quotes_gpc is on should i make off ?

Comment: Yep. That will prevent \ being added before ' and " in `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `SQL` strings being passed around through your server.

I have mine set to `Off` at all times.

Comment: should i use ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', '0'); on my php page

Comment: either will work the same. `ini_set()` is just if you want to change something from default in `php.ini` for this script.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that has to do with TinyMCE, but with your server.

There is an PHP option called [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) that automatically adds slashes before quotes.

[`phpinfo()`](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) would show if magic quotes are turned on.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$_REQUEST['text'] = stripslashes($_REQUEST['text']);
```

This will strip off the "\", I think they are there cause of the PHP directive magic_quotes_gpc.

Comment: im using `$terms= mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['terms']));` and then im storing $terms into db

Comment: Directly from the php manual of mysql_real_escape_string:

"Note:
If magic_quotes_gpc is enabled, first apply stripslashes() to the data. Using this function on data which has already been escaped will escape the data twice."

So you should do: `$terms= stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['terms'])));`

Comment: still giving me the same output with \ and how to enable magic_quotes_gpc ? sorry im new to this

Comment: Like Ikke said, put `phpinfo()` somewhere in your page and look for magic_quotes_gpc. Anyway the correct syntax for what I suggested before is: `$terms= mysql_real_escape_string(trim(stripslashes($_POST['terms'])));`

Comment: this code is also not running....really i dont know why this is happening,at localhost it is running properly what happen on server

Comment: magic_quotes_runtime and magic_quotes_sybase are off but magic_quotes_gpc is on should i make off ?

Comment: should i use ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', '0'); on my php page

Comment: No, you can't disable magic_quotes_gps via ini_set. You should edit the php.ini file or (if you can't access the ini file) add a rule in your .htaccess file: `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off`. Read here for more information: [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

As last resort try:
`$terms = stripslashes($_POST['terms']);`

`$terms = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($terms));`

Comment: Thanks buddy.. i wrote `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` on my .htaccess file it works.Thank you very much for your help